# How to dump MySQL table to a file then read it and use it in place of the DB itself?

Tags: php, mysql, json

because a provider I use, has a quite unreliable MySQL servers, which are down at leas 1 time pr week :-/ impacting one of the sites I made, I want to prevent its outeges in the following way:

- dump the MySQL table to a file In case the connection with the SQL
  server is failed,
- then read the file instead of the Server, till the Server is back.

This will avoid outages from the user experience point of view.
In fact things are not so easy like it seems and I ask for your help please.

What I did is to save the data to a JSON file format.
But this got issues because many data on the DB are "in clear" included escaped complex URLs, with long argument's line, that give some issue during the decode process from JSON.
On CSV and TSV is also not workign correctly.
CSV is delimited by Commas or Semilcolon , and those are present in the original content taken from the DB.
TSV format leave double quotes that are not deletable, without avoid to go to eliminate them into the record's fields

Then I tried to serialize each record read from the DB, store it and retrive it serializing it.
But the result is a bit catastrophic, becase all the records are stored in the file.
When I retrieve them, only one is returned. then there is something that blocks the functioning of the program (here below the code please)

```
require_once('variables.php');
require_once("database.php");
$file = "database.dmp";

$myfile = fopen($file, "w") or die("Unable to open file!");

$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM song ORDER BY ID ASC");
    // output data of each row
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql)) {
    // store the record into the file
    fwrite($myfile, serialize($row));
    }
fclose($myfile);
mysql_close();


// Retrieving section
$myfile = fopen($file, "r") or die("Unable to open file!");

// Till the file is not ended, continue to check it
    while ( !feof($myfile) ) {
        $record = fgets($myfile); // get the record
        $row = unserialize($record); // unserialize it
        print_r($row); // show if the variable has something on it
     }
fclose($myfile);
```

I tried also to uuencode and also with base64_encode but they were worse choices.

Is there any way to achieve my goal?

Thank you very much in advance for your help

Comment: don't you use `exec` in php to do that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After `SELECT...` you need to create a correct structure for inserting data, then you can serialize or what you want.
For example: 
 You have a row, you could do that - `$sqls[] = "INSERT INTO`song`(field1,field2,..  fieldN) VALUES(field1_value, field2_value, ... fieldN_value);";`
Than you could serialize this `$sqls`, write into file, and when you need it, you could read, unserialize and make query.

Comment: the first part of the code, retrieve data from DB, do not insert anything on it.
And the goal is to write the data into a file, then retrieve it, (all the records), and use them at the place of the original DB. This only when the official DB is outage.

Answer (score 2):

If you have your data layer well decoupled you can consider using SQLite as a fallback storage.

It's just a matter of adding one abstraction more, with the same code accessing the storage and changing the storage target in case of unavailability of the primary one.

-----EDIT-----
You could also try to think about some caching (json/html file?!) strategy returning stale data in case of mysql outage.

-----EDIT 2-----
If it's not too much effort, please consider playing with [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/class.pdo.php), I'm quite sure you'll never look back and believe me this will help you structuring your db calls with little pain when switching between storages.

> Please take the following only as an example, there are much better
>   way to design this architectural part of code.

Just a small and basic code to demonstrate you what I mean:

```
class StoragePersister
{
    private $driver = 'mysql';

    public function setDriver($driver)
    {
        $this->driver = $driver;
    }

    public function persist($data) 
    { 
        switch ($this->driver)
        {
            case 'mysql':
                $this->persistToMysql($data);
            case 'sqlite':
                $this->persistToSqlite($data);
        }
    }

    public function persistToMysql($data)
    {
        //query to mysql
    }

    public function persistSqlite($data)
    {
        //query to Sqlite
    }

}

$storage = new StoragePersister;
$storage->setDriver('sqlite'); //eventually to switch to sqlite
$storage->persist($somedata); // this will use the strategy to call the function based on the storage driver you've selected.
```

-----EDIT 3-----
please give a look at the "[strategy](http://www.phptherightway.com/pages/Design-Patterns.html)" design pattern section, I guess it can help to better understand what I mean.

Comment: I can't install anything on the server. the provider has access to libraries etc. The only one thing I can do is to work with php/cgi ...

Comment: Maybe it's already installed, did you check with extension_loaded('sqlite3')?
And please follow @alfallouji suggest; Try to start using PDO abstraction instead of the deprecated mysql_*

Comment: Honestly I have not tried the function you proposed. I loaded now and it returns 1.
About the PDO: i was not aware that "mysql" functions were deprecated. I will have to rewrite the PHP files ti implement PDO instead of, at this point ...

Comment: returning 1 means you have sqlite3 at your disposal, try to play with it (http://php.net/manual/en/book.sqlite3.php) to see if it helps you come up with something.

Comment: responding to your first edit: As I said, i tried JSON, but there are issues with

Comment: Yes, sorry, you're right. And what about keeping a cache in between with the output in html files? Maybe it can be a way to avoid hitting the db while down.

Comment: in this case you mean: XML file?

Comment: No, I mean you keep a copy of the already rendered output in a html file, to serve this one instead of making a call to the db when visiting a page or your site. Since we don't know anything about your site It's just a possible way and not a solution. Sorry, this doesn't directly answer your question but maybe it can help.

Comment: Yes perhaps it's possible, but the site has also some dynamic widget like a list that's imported by an iframe etc ... it means: to make a duplicate of the website in a static way ... and it must not be accessible by an,y user when the MySQL database is running

Comment: Yes, then give a try to sqlite3...probably it's the right way

Comment: ok I finished to sucesfully switch teh site to PDO.
now, to use SQLite I should create a mirror of the DB into it and then retrieving form it, istnea do MySQL, when this is outage. using the Class you porposed ... am i right?

Comment: Well done. Yes, the raw logic is that one. The class I "proposed" is just a strategy to investigate on. The idea is to always keep the same queries to retrieve the data but, in case of a mysql problem, switching to a different db with little effort (switching a param to set the desired storage). Then how you could mirror it, how/when you could check the mysql status, etc...is left to your play and investigation., too much wider discussion to have it here...

Comment: Great. i finished now to create the table, and to import 2 records to try  the synthax and the PHP Code (quite trivial, but fortunately the table is not so big, and I can elaborate a calss, in order to automatize the function).
I think the suggestion of SQLite and the whole your help are the best solution, and I adopt it immediately. Thank you so much :)

Answer (score 0):

Have you thought about caching your queries into a cache like APC ? Also, you may want to use `mysqli` or `pdo` instead of mysql (Mysql is deprecated in the latest versions of PHP).

To answer your question, this is one way of doing it.

- `var_export` will export the variable as valid PHP code
- `require` will put the content of the array into the $data variable (because of the `return` statement)

Here is the code :

```
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM song ORDER BY ID ASC");
$content = array();

// output data of each row
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql)) {
    // store the record into the file
    $content[$row['ID']] = $row;
}
mysql_close();

$data = '<?php return ' . var_export($content, true) . ';';
file_put_contents($file, $data);

// Retrieving section
$rows = require $file;
```

Comment: thus in ther $row variable at the very end shoudl I find the whole record as Array with couples Index['Velue'] right?

Adn iterating it into the "While ( !eof())" should I get each record from the file. Am I right?

Comment: After your suggestion, I'm implementing the PDO on the site as priority. then i will check the list above and then your suggestion and the one of @ilpaijin